# I have problem while inserting data to Hive in ubuntu terminal

Tags: apache-spark, hive

```
hive> INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, age, email)
    > VALUES
    >   (1, 'John Doe', 25, 'john.doe@example.com'),
    >   (2, 'Jane Smith', 30, 'jane.smith@example.com');
```

Query ID = qossay_20230509170006_1097a8a7-49b9-4ad3-a521-47ca9432311d

Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
set hive.exec.reducers.max=
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
set mapreduce.job.reduces=
Starting Job = job_1683629689937_0009, Tracking URL = http://qossay-zeineddin:8088/proxy/application_1683629689937_0009/
Kill Command = /home/qossay/hadoop-3.3.5/bin/mapred job  -kill job_1683629689937_0009

```
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2023-05-09 17:00:21,436 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_1683629689937_0009 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5H3g.png)

I want to add values to this table and try to run select query
the table

```
   CREATE TABLE test (id INT,name STRING, age INT,email STRING ) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    STORED AS TEXTFILE
    LOCATION '/home/qossay/Documents'
    TBLPROPERTIES ('serialization.format'='1');`
```

Comment: There is error from Mapreduce Task. Check the log for same

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.